# How to make a row of checkboxes, each one revealing different text?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting back into HTML after years of not touching it, so I'm still working on the basics!

Basically what I want to do is have a row of checkboxes, and each one when checked will reveal a different text beneath it. So it would look like:

**Heading**

(x)Box 1 ()Box 2 ()Box 3 ()Box 4 ()Box 5

**Text for Box 1**

...with Box 2 displaying Text for Box 2, etc. If that makes sense. This is what I have so far for making the checkbox reveal text when checked:

```js
 function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true) {
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">
<label for="myCheck">Box 1</label>
<p id="text" style="display:none">Text for Box 1</p>
```

That's what trying to do, but having 5 boxes all in the same row, with different labels and hidden text corresponding to each. If you could help me figure that out, as well as tell me what part needs to be changed for each box for them all to remain separate, I'd really appreciate that!

Comment: I suggest you researched tab widgets.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution.
Align to left Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2czamtfr/2/ 
Keep in column Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2czamtfr/3/

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1" onclick="myFunction(1)">
<label for="myCheck">Box 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2" onclick="myFunction(2)">
<label for="myCheck">Box 2</label>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p id="text1" style="display:none">Text for Box 1</p>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p id="text2" style="display:none">Text for Box 2</p>
    </td>
   </tr>
</table>

<script>
   function myFunction(x) {
     var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck"+x);
     var text = document.getElementById("text"+x);
     if (checkBox.checked == true) {
        text.style.display = "block";
     }
     else {
        text.style.display = "none";
     }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow community. I confirmed this works so it gets an up from me.

Answer (score 0):

One implementation variant might be (I'm not using loops here for simplicity. Usually, you would create your list using a loop in JavaScript. I'll just copy/paste your controls here):

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck1" onclick="myFunction(1)">
<label for="myCheck">Box 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck2" onclick="myFunction(2)">
<label for="myCheck">Box 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck3" onclick="myFunction(3)">
<label for="myCheck">Box 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck4" onclick="myFunction(4)">
<label for="myCheck">Box 4</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck5" onclick="myFunction(5)">
<label for="myCheck">Box 5</label>

<p id="text1" style="display:none">Text for Box 1</p>
<p id="text2" style="display:none">Text for Box 2</p>
<p id="text3" style="display:none">Text for Box 3</p>
<p id="text4" style="display:none">Text for Box 4</p>
<p id="text5" style="display:none">Text for Box 5</p>

<script>
  function myFunction(idx) {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck" + idx);
    var text = document.getElementById("text" + idx);
    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
      text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      text.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
```